# Evaluation of $-\int e^{\cos(t)}\sin(\sin(t)+t)\,dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How would I integrate this:

$$-\int e^{\cos(t)}\sin(\sin(t)+t)\,dt $$

I have tried several methods but can't seem to work this out.

Comment: Which methods have you tried?

Comment: I original attempted it by inspection, then I tried integration by parts which got extremely messy. I tried substitution by I'm not very good at that

Comment: I would play around with the identity $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}[e^{ix}-e^{-ix}]$.

Comment: I hadn't considered this thank you

Comment: Not sure if that will solve it, but it will give you a way to combine exponents.

Comment: I'll post an answer below with the integral rewritten, if you'd like

Comment: expand $\sin(\sin(t)+t)$

Comment: I cant seem to solve it

Answer (score 7):

If you are allowed to use complex number, this integral can be integrated by
repeat application of the [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin\theta$$

Up to integration constant, the integral is equal to:

$$\begin{align}\int -e^{\cos t}\sin(\sin t + t) dt
&= - \int e^{\cos t}\Im\left[e^{i(\sin t + t)}\right] dt
\stackrel{\color{blue}{[1]}}{=} - \Im \left[\int e^{\cos t + i(\sin t + t)} dt \right]\\
&=  - \Im \left[\int e^{e^{it}} e^{it} dt\right]
=  \Im \left[ i\int e^{e^{it}} d e^{it}\right]\\
&= \Re\left[ e^{e^{it}} \right]
= \Re\left[ e^{\cos t + i\sin t} \right]\\
&= \, e^{\cos t} \cos(\sin t)
\end{align}
$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - At this step, the integral is an ordinary integral of a complex valued function along the real axis. There is no issue of moving the $\Im[\cdots]$ outside the integral sign.

Comment: But $\operatorname{Im}\int f(z) \, \mathrm dz = \int \operatorname{Im} f(z) \, \mathrm dz$ is false in general? Consider $\int \operatorname{Log} z \, \mathrm dz$.

Comment: @GFauxPax This is not complex contour integral, it is integral of  a complex valued function along real axis. $\int \Im\left[f\right]dz = \int \Im\left[f dz\right] = \Im\left[\int f dz\right]$ does work in such cases.

Comment: So you can always move $\operatorname{Im}$ and $\operatorname{Re}$ into and out of the integral if $z$ is wholly real?

Comment: @GFauxPas Yes. you can move $\Im$ and $\Re$ into and out if $z$ is always real.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$e^{\cos t} \sin(\sin(t) + t) = e^{\cos t} \left( \sin(\sin t)\cos t + \cos(\sin t)\sin t \right)$$ which is equal to $$-\left(e^{\cos t}(\cos t)'\cos(\sin t) + e^{\cos t}(\cos(\sin t))'\right)$$

Got it from here?

Comment: I don't understand the first line?

Comment: The first line is applying this identity $$\sin(a + b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b$$ where $a = \sin t, b = t$

Comment: Next one can use the formulae  $$\int e^{g(x)}[f'(x) + g'(x)f(x)] dx = f(x) e^{g(x)}+C$$    which is proved here  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472748/proof-for-formula-int-egxfx-gxfx-dx-fx-egxc/1472751#1472751