# using contour integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Let $ \gamma (t)= e^{it} $ where $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi.$

Evaluate $\int_{\gamma}$ $e^{z}$ $dz$ .

Use the result to show that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos(t)}\cos(t+ \sin(t)) dt = 0$.

I have worked out the first contour integral to be 0 but I am unsure of how the result can help in showing the other integral.

Comment: If you want to see it evaluated without complex analysis, check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031420/a-hard-integration-question) post which ironically wasn't posted that long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Write down direct value of integral using parametrization:

$$\oint_{\gamma}e^{z}dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}ie^{it}dt=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}+it}dt=\\=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos t+i\sin(t)+it}dt$$

But:

$$e^{i(t+\sin t)}=\cos(t+\sin(t))+i\sin(t+\sin(t))$$

So:

$$i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos t+i\sin(t)+it}dt=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(t)}\cos(t+\sin(t))dt-\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(t)}\sin(t+\sin(t))dt$$

So $0=\Im(\oint_{\gamma}e^{z}dz)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(t)}\cos(t+\sin(t))dt$.

Comment: this helps a lot thank you but could I just ask where the second integral goes? the one with the sin(t+sin(t))?

Comment: Yes, simply put $e^{i(t+\sin t)}=\cos(t+\sin(t))+i\sin(t+\sin(t))$ and use fact, that $i^2=-1$.